# How to exclude XCFramework from Catalyst?

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, swift-package-manager

### Given that

There is an iOS app that needs Analytics and it's decided to use Amazon as a provider. So I added Amplify, and it works ok on iOS and on Simulator. But when building for Mac Catalyst, compiler produces a set of similar errors related to various XCFrameowrk's from Amplify bundle:

> While building for Mac Catalyst, no library for this platform was
> found in '... artifacts/AWSiOSSDKV2/AWSCore.xcframework'.

Quick search shows that Amazon do not want to support Catalyst due to [business reasons](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/pull/2065#issuecomment-563406435) and there an open [issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/issues/1124) on this topic, and the first PR was raised 3 years ago then accidentally closed.

### Attempts to avoid the error

Analytics isn't absolutely necessary feature, so I tried to remove Amplify libraries from Catalyst and keep them on iOS. I'm using this macro (which obviously is compile-time, not build-time, but some SO answers reported that it may help):

```
#if !TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST
import Amplify
import AWSPinpointAnalyticsPlugin
import AWSCognitoAuthPlugin
#endif
```

Then in **Link Binary With Libraries** I set Amplify-related libs to be Optional. In Filter section I removed checkmarks near Mac Catalyst, thinking  that it will make them iOS-only:

[image: Xcode Link Binary With Libraries]

All this tricks combined together didn't help and I'm still getting the same errors.

### Q

How to exclude XCFramework for certain unsupported platforms?

### P.S.

Seems, like a new [AWS SDK](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-swift), which claims to support Catalyst, is emerging. But it's raw and low level, and I simply not ready to debug it and build my own Analytis framework on top of it in scope of this question.

Comment: For Firebase, the only solution we found was adding the missing Catalyst slice to the xcframework. Context at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7043

Comment: @PaulBeusterien, can you, please, share your implementation?

Comment: We use this tooling to build binary distributions from libraries specified with CocoaPods source podspecs - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/tree/master/ReleaseTooling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the exact answer regarding Swift PM. But I was able to fix my issue, just switched to good old (and much more flexible) cocoapods. I used [cocoapods-catalyst-support](https://github.com/fermoya/cocoapods-catalyst-support) to restrict Amplify to iOS only. My podfile:

```
require 'cocoapods-catalyst-support'

platform :ios, '14.1'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'Amplify'
  pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSPinpointAnalyticsPlugin'
  pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'Amplify'
    pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSPinpointAnalyticsPlugin'
    pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin'
  end
end

catalyst_configuration do
  ios 'Amplify'
  ios 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSPinpointAnalyticsPlugin'
  ios 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.configure_catalyst
end
```

I basically did the same thing, @PaulBeusterien recommended in comments, but the framework is generated by cocoapods instead of Firebase ReleaseTooling.

Swift Package Manager do not support platform filters, as for Feb 2022. I contacted swift forums and Amazon support and also did my own research.